# Sum of positive definite and symmetric matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real, symmetric, positive definite $n\times n$ matrix. Let $B$ be a real, symmetric $n\times n$ matrix.

Does there exist an $\epsilon>0$ such that $A+\epsilon B$ is positive definite?

My attempt: According to Wikipedia we can simultaneously diagonalize $A$ and $B$. Since $A$ is positive definite, its eigenvalues are all positive. Call them $\lambda_i$. Let $\rho_i$ be the eigenvalues of $B$. Choose a basis which simultaneously diagonalizes $A$ and $B$. Then $$u^T(A+\epsilon B)u=u^TAu+\epsilon u^TBu=\sum_i(\lambda_i+\epsilon \rho_{i})u_i^2.$$ So if $$\epsilon<\frac{\lambda_{\min}}{|\rho_{\max}|}$$ (assume $B\neq 0$), then $$\lambda_i+\epsilon\rho_i>\lambda_i-\lambda_{\min}\geq0$$ for all $i$, which implies $A+\epsilon B$ is positive definite.

Is this valid? Is there a basis-independent way to show this?

Comment: Can you provide a link to where Wikipedia says A and B can be simultaneously diagonalized?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization

Comment: If you carefully read the entry you point to, you will find that it discusses a form of joint diagonalization which does not lead to the traditional eigenvalues for the two matrices.  At least one of the diagonal results is necessarily the identity matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sought for conclusion binds since the eigenvalues of a matrix depend continuously on its entries; then as $A + \epsilon B$ is continuous in $\epsilon$, and agrees with $A$ for $\epsilon = 0$, all eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $A + \epsilon B$ are positive for $\vert \epsilon \vert$ sufficiently small, so $A + \epsilon B$ is positive definite for such $\epsilon$.

Comment: Well what do you know?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization !!!

Comment: Is it correct to then say that such an argument holds for any matrix $B$, i.e., $B$ does not need to be symmetric (only that $A$ is positive definite)?

Answer (score 4):

You can make this line of reasoning work, but you should be careful about what "diagonalized" means in this context.  In particular, [your wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization) is talking about diagonalization via a [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) rather than a similarity.

In particular, the theorem is that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ (not necessarily orthogonal) such that both $PAP^T$ and $PBP^T$ are diagonal.  Note that the diagonal entries will not generally be the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

---

Note that we can't necessarily diagonalize $A$ and $B$ simultaneously in the sense of similarity.  In fact, we can do so if and only if $AB = BA$.

It is generally true that if $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, then such an $\epsilon$ exists.  One proof is as follows:

If $A$ is positive definite, then for some $r > 0$ (e.g. $r = \lambda_{min}$) we can write
$$
A = rI + (A - rI)
$$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix and $A - rI$ is positive semidefinite.  With that, we have
$$
A + B\epsilon = [rI + \epsilon B] + (A - rI)
$$
It suffices to choose an $\epsilon$ such that $rI + \epsilon B$ is positive definite.

---

Another approach that I like: let $A^{-1/2}$ denote the positive definite square root of $A^{-1}$.  Then $A + \epsilon B$ is positive definite if and only if the matrix
$$
A^{-1/2}(A + \epsilon B)A^{-1/2} = I + \epsilon A^{-1/2}B(A^{-1/2})^T
$$
is positive definite.  It therefore suffices to consider the case with $A = I$.

If you choose to diagonalize $I + \epsilon A^{-1/2}B(A^{-1/2})^T$ by diagonalizing the symmetric matrix $A^{-1/2}B(A^{-1/2})^T$, then you are essentially deriving the "simultaneous diagonalizability" of quadratic forms in our specific case.